# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requote'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Chiyo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 34, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import BaseConnector as BaseConnector
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 30, in <module>
    from yarl import URL
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._url import URL, cache_clear, cache_configure, cache_info
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 56, in <module>
    @rewrite_module
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 132, in URL
    _QUERY_PART_QUOTER = _Quoter(safe="?/:@", qs=True, requote=False)
  File "yarl/_quoting.pyx", line 192, in yarl._quoting._Quoter.__init__
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requote'
```

I got this error after updated discord.py and I don't know how to fix it :c

using python3.6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install yarl 1.4.2 `pip install -U yarl==1.4.2`